# How to globally set an application's background to an image in windows store app?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

i'm trying to set an image to the background in my application, now i know how to set background to an image locally using

`<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Background.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>`

How can i do this globally,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it:
1. Add style to your resources without name, so it will apply to every element of that type:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/SplashScreen.png"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

2. Add style with name and apply it whenever you need

```
<Page.Resources>
<Style x:Key="ImageStyle"  TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/SplashScreen.png"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}">
</Grid>
```

Comment: i changed the "Background" property in the x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" in the StandardStyles.xaml file as you specified and it worked fine thanks alot